# Optimize Input Vector to achieve optimal results

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I couldn't figure out the following problem: if I may, I'd like to give you right away an example
Imagine, you work with marketing data and you came up with a good regression model, predicting the "reach" of a certain campaign. All fine and dandy. Data Scientist Job done.
But wait. We can do more.
**My question to you is:**
Assuming that we have a good model, how can we optimize the input vector ( = marketing campaign) to get the best possible "reach" ( = predictor / goal to optimize)?
I was googling like crazy, but couldn't find any good approach (I am not talking about any hypterparameter optimization). The *best* approach I found so far is a **genetic algorithm**... example [here](https://blog.sicara.com/getting-started-genetic-algorithms-python-tutorial-81ffa1dd72f9) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/evolution-of-a-salesman-a-complete-genetic-algorithm-tutorial-for-python-6fe5d2b3ca35)
Or - a brute force approach -  calculate an enormous grid with tons of possible input vectors and then check, which one is the best (straight forward) - but that would be computational expensive.

I would love to hear your opinion on this. Any advice on which topics I should check out?

Comment: Sounds initially like a MILP to me. How big is your problem? What do your 'reach' values/functions look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very long comment:

Genetic algorithms can be nested. Put your genetic solution finder into a fitness function. Give it to a parent genetic algorithm. Have them search results by "optimizing input vector" from outer GA and "optimizing goal" from inner GA.

You can even add a third layer of GA, to test the construction parameters of middle layer GA because we may not know what kind of search space we need. If we knew it, then we wouldn't need to optimize that vector.

You can even decrease dimensions of problem per GA this way.

```
vector:x,y,z

GA1: optimizes x and GA2 parameters
  GA2: optimizes y and GA3 parameters
     GA3: optimizes z
        fitness(x,y,z)
all pass their best fitness to parent
```

I'm not sure if it would be faster/slower than

```
GA: optimize x,y,z
    fitness(x,y,z)
```

because I don't know if mutation of GA3 can save whole optimizer from a local minima. Also other version:

```
GA1: optimize GA2
   GA2: optimize x,y,z
       fitness(x,y,z)
```

I don't know its performance. Maybe GA can solve that how many nested GAs should be there too

```
GA0: optimize N, x0,x1,..xM-N
  GA1: optimize XM-N+1
    GA2: optimize XM-N+2
       ...
           GAM: optimize XM
               fitness(X0,X1,..XM)
```

but I guess having too many objects constructed/destructed on all levels would decrease performance(memory bandiwdth related) and readability(callback hell).